# Would a double ever be implicitly converted to an unsigned int in arithmetic expressions?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

In *C++ Primer*, by Stanley B. Lippman, the section on "Implicit Conversions" says that:

> ```
>   int ival; 
>   unsigned int ui;
>   float fval;
>
>   fval = ui - ival * 1.0;
> ```
>
> `ival` is converted to double, then multiplied by `1.0`. The result is
>    converted to `unsigned int`, then subtracted by `ui`. The result is
>      converted to `float`, then assigned to `fval`.

But I don't think so: I think that in fact `ival` is converted to double then multiplied by `1.0` then `ui` is which is of type `unsigned int` is converted to double not the contrary and then the result of multiplication is subtracted from the converted to converted to double `ui` value. finally convert this final double value to float and assign it to `fval`.

To ensure what I say:

```
ival = 5; 
ui  = 10;
fval = 7.22f;
dval = 3.14;

std::cout << typeid(ui - ival * 1.0).name() << std::endl; // double

std::cout << (ui - ival * 1.7) << std::endl; // 1.5 this proves that the unsigned int ui is converted to double not the contrary that is because C++ preserves precision. otherwise the decimal part is truncated.
```

Comment: I think that the question should have been phrased as "is this subtraction being done on unsigned ints or doubles?" The middle paragraph was confusingly written and, I think, contains a grammatical error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is correct and the book is wrong.

```
fval = ui - ival * 1.0;
```

can be rewritten as

```
fval = ui - (ival * 1.0);
```

so that gives us

```
float = unsigned - (int * double)
```

The `(int * double)` becomes a `double` because of the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions) giving us

```
float = unsigned - double
```

which again results is in a `double` and we assign that `double` to the `float` variable.